# Maximizing compound interest with fee per compound

Tags: finance

Given the following:

initial principle $P$, interest rate $r$, flat fee whenever interest is applied $x$, period between applying interest $p$, total time period $t$

How do I calculate the final amount $A$?

the objective is to maximize $A$ by tuning $p$.

---

The context of this problem is staking cryptocurrencies and compounding their rewards

Comment: Is $r$ the yearly interest rate, or the interest rate per period $p$?

Comment: @PaulSinclair yearly interest rate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presuming that both $p$ and $t$ are measured in years, the number of compoundings per year is $\frac 1p$, and the interest rate for each period is the yearly interest rate divided by the number of compounding per year, or $r_p = \dfrac r{\frac 1p} = pr$.

At the end of the first period, an amount equal to $Ppr - x$ is added to the account (where $r$ is expressed as a fraction out of $1$, not as a percent), totalling

$$P_1 = P + Ppr - x = P(1+pr) - x$$

To make this a little easier, let $a = (1+pr)$, so $P_1 = Pa - x$.

At the end of the second period, the calculation is the same, except the beginning principle $P$ is replaced by the amount $P_1$ in the account at the beginning of the period.
$$\begin{align}P_2 &= P_1a - x\\&= (Pa - x)a - x\\&= Pa^2 - xa - x\\&=Pa^2 - x(a +1)\end{align}$$
Continuing we see that
$$P_3 = Pa^3 - x(a^2 + a + 1)\\P_4 = Pa^4 - x(a^3 + a^2 + a + 1)\\\vdots$$

Now this sum of powers is well known. If you multiply it by $a-1$ you get
$$\begin{align}(a-1)(a^{n-1} + a^{n-2} + \cdots + a + 1) &= a(a^{n-1} + a^{n-2} + \cdots + a + 1)\\&\qquad-(a^{n-1} + a^{n-2} + \cdots + a + 1)\\&=(a^n + a^{n-1} + \cdots + a^2 + a)\\&\qquad - (a^{n-1} + a^{n-2} + \cdots + a + 1)\\&=a^n - 1\end{align}$$
so
$$a^{n-1} + a^{n-2} + \cdots + a + 1 = \dfrac{a^n - 1}{a - 1}$$
And we can write
$$P_n = Pa^n - x\dfrac{a^n - 1}{a - 1}$$

The number $n$ of periods is going to be $n = \frac tp$. And noting that $a - 1 = pr$, this becomes
$$\begin{align}A &= Pa^{t/p} - x \frac{a^{t/p} - 1}{pr}\\&=Pa^{t/p}-\frac x{pr}a^{t/p}+\frac x{pr}\\&=\left(P-\frac x{pr}\right)a^{t/p} + \frac x{pr}\end{align}$$
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid] {A =\left(P-\frac x{pr}\right)\left(1+pr\right)^{t/p} + \frac x{pr}}$$

Comment: Nice! Is it straightforward to modify the fee to $x + y \times (i-1)$ where $i$ is the ith compound? Meaning the fee increases linearly by y each time you compound? If not, I'll just accept this answer and make a new question.

Comment: It will be significantly more messy, but should be accomplishable, giving something *similar to* $P_n = Pa^n - x\dfrac{a^n - 1}{a - 1} - y\dfrac{na^n}{(a-1)^2}$ (almost certainly this is not correct, but the general form ought to be). Go ahead and ask a new question.

Comment: Heres the new question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3975735/271952